# How to avoid async behviour of node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous

I am uploading multiple files and saving in some directory. My code is as below

```
app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
  var msgs = '';

  req.files.forEach(function(element) {
   var fileNameToWrite = __dirname + "\\uploads\\" + element.originalname;
   fs.readFile( element.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(fileNameToWrite, data, function (err) {
         if( err ){
              msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Failed Error: '"+ err +"' ";
         }
         else{
              msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Successfully ";
          }
       });
   });
  },this);
  console.log("Final Msgs: " + msgs);
  res.end( JSON.stringify( msgs ) );
});
```

The problem is **msgs** is populated asynchronously, I want to get msgs once forEach is complete. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question here, you don't want to get rid of the asynchronous behaviour as that would kill the user experience. Instead you should find a way to execute your code once all requests have completed. Unfortunately I don't know enough about node to tell you how to do this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry about this question this is not related here i read on one of your answer NEVER TO USE ASYNC FALSE on ajax can you tell why thank you

Comment: It's because running requests synchronously locks the browser's UI. This means that to the user, the browser will appear locked, and that it has crashed until all the requests have completed.

Comment: thank you for that i hope i can link you to a question i commented like that because i read it on your comment somewhere but i cant remember. anyway thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would go for to make the asynchronous functions not seem so asynchronous are [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). In particular the [Bluebird promise library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) is excellent. In essence, your function could look like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var readFile = Promise.promisify(require('fs').readFile);

app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
  var msgs = '';

  req.files.forEach(function(element) {
    var fileNameToWrite = __dirname + "\\uploads\\" + element.originalname;
    readFile(element.path).then(function (data) {
      return writeFile(filenameToWrite, data);
    }).then(function () {
      msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Successfully ";
    }).catch(function () {
      msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Failed Error: '"+ err +"' ";
    }).then(function () {
      console.log("Final Msgs: " + msgs);
      res.end( JSON.stringify( msgs ) );
    });
  },this);
});
```

This keeps all the goodiness of asynchronous calls (e.g. not locking the running thread), making your API quick and responsive. Still, it let's you write code "as if" if was synchronous by just chaining `then`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get rid of the asynchronous code, you can use `writeFileSync` and `readFileSync`. But it is not a good pratice.

A simple way is to use a callback like this :

```
app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
  var msgs = '';

  function finish() {
    console.log("Final Msgs: " + msgs);
    res.end( JSON.stringify( msgs ) );
  }

  var counter = 0;

  req.files.forEach(function(element) {
   var fileNameToWrite = __dirname + "\\uploads\\" + element.originalname;
   fs.readFile( element.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(fileNameToWrite, data, function (err) {
         if( err ){
              msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Failed Error: '"+ err +"' ";
         }
         else{
              msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Successfully ";
          }

         // We call the finish when we write the last file
         counter += 1;
         if (counter == req.files.length) {
             finish();
         }
       });
   });
  },this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use several approaches,

1.Use [`writefilesync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options) instead of `fs.writeFile`, like this

```
req.files.forEach(function(element) {
  var fileNameToWrite = __dirname + "\\uploads\\" + element.originalname;

  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(fileNameToWrite, data);
    msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Successfully ";
  } catch(err) {
    msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Failed Error: '"+ err +"' ";
  }
}, this);
```

2.Or use libraries like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) (`npm i async --save-dev`), like so

```
var async = require('async');
var msgs = '';

async.eachSeries(req.files, function (element, next) {
  var fileNameToWrite = __dirname + "\\uploads\\" + element.originalname;

  fs.readFile(element.path, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Failed Error: '"+ err +"' ";
    } else {
      msgs += element.originalname + " Uploaded Successfully ";
    }

    next();
  });  
}, function () {
  console.log("Final Msgs: " + msgs);
  res.end( JSON.stringify( msgs ) );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nomi
I would recommend to change following things which will help you to gain much performance.

1.Change your file upload from single post request to multiple post requests. I meant, you should change your front-end code to send separate post request to each file.

2.Keep a tracker/count variable in each JavaScript request. Basically, the counter value initially same as number of files. Then reduce by 1, when each file fully uploaded. And you can show the success message, when the counter value reaches 0. Probably, you can use promise for this file tracking.

3.Modify your server-side code to handle file upload request in streaming mode. You may want to see the following server-side code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
app.post('/file_upload', function(req, res) {
  // Read file name and extension from request header and replace 'somefile.someExtension' below.
  var fileNameToWrite = __dirname + "\\uploads\\" + 'somefile.someExtension';
  var wStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileNameToWrite);
  req.pipe(wStream);
});
```

Hopefully, this will give you an alternate idea.